# Dataform calling a function with Query extracted value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform

I need to execute a function and return a value.  The function takes as input a date, which has to be extracted from a table.  All this needs one with GCP dataform.
So I have a pre_op in .sqlx file-

```
pre_operations {
  declare lastTime default (
    select max(DATE(lastRunTime)) FROM ${self()}
  )

}
```

This needs to be passed to a function in a .js file like so-

```
${functions.isRunCheck(lastRunTime)}
```

Unfortunaltely data form does not detect 'lastRunTime' and gives error **lastRunTime is not defined**
Is there a certain way of passing the values extracted thourgh declare in dataform?

Comment: Can you share the documentation you are following for this one and the steps to replicate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

So from what I could gather, we cannot have a variable initialized and used in a function call.  It can be used in SQL texts.
Accordingly deployed the dataform, using the variable as an input to the SQL query, instead of generating code from a function with the variable value.